# React-Native Segments with animation

Tags: react-native

I want to achieve this exact scenario in React-Native
[image]

Is there any package or code that help me achieve this scenario.
P.S: I just need this tab selection not a component that requires data to show it below

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the package but you can achieve that easily. Create a horizontal flatlist component for the tabs to change the state and display the data accordingly. You can add styling to your button relevantly too.

An example can be:

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const Splash = (props) => {
  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          {
            width: width * 0.4,
            height: height * 0.1,
            borderRadius: width * 0.2,
            borderColor: "grey",
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginLeft: width * 0.05,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          },
          Selected === index && {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: "#FC5900",
          },
        ]}
        onPress={() => setSelected(index)}>
        <Text style={{ color: Selected === index ? "white" : "black" }}>
          {item}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const GetData = () => {
    switch (Selected) {
      case 0:
        return <Text>This is the supermarket section</Text>;
      case 1:
        return <Text>This is the Coffee section</Text>;
      case 2:
        return <Text>This is the Tea section</Text>;
      case 3:
        return <Text>This is the Green Tea section</Text>;
      default:
        return <Text>This is the default section</Text>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          width: width,
          height: height * 0.1,
          marginTop: height * 0.2,
        }}>
        <FlatList
          horizontal
          data={["SuperMarkets", "Coffee", "Tea", "Green Tea"]}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, idx) => idx.toString()}
          ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ marginLeft: width * 0.05 }} />}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          width: width * 0.9,
          marginTop: height * 0.05,
          alignSelf: "center",
        }}>
        {GetData()}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
export default Splash;
```

[here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IILq.jpg)